# Showing an empty cell when data is null with DefaultCellStyle.Format set

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview.  The dgv's data source is a 'ReadOnlyCollection' of objects.  One of the properties of the object in the 'ReadOnlyCollection' is a nullable 'DateTime'.  What I'm trying to do is show a blank cell where the 'DateTime' is null, but apply a different format to the DateTime column, by doing:

```
TimeOutColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
```

The only problem is that sets all of my null entries to the DateTime.Min value.

'history' is the ReadOnlyCollection.
Here's the current code:

```
'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn TimeOutColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            TimeOutColumn.DataPropertyName = "timeout";
            TimeOutColumn.HeaderText = "Time Out";                

            ddgGHistory.Columns.Add(BadgeTypeIDColumn);
            ddgGHistory.Columns.Add(EmployeeColumn);
            ddgGHistory.Columns.Add(TimeInColumn);
            ddgGHistory.Columns.Add(TimeOutColumn);

            ddgGHistory.DataSource = history

            ddgGHistory.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
            ddgGHistory.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a non-nullable object, it must have a value.  However, it is possible to make `DateTime` nullable by declaring it as a nullable `DateTime`.

The following is a non-nullable datetime, and will always have a value.

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

However,one can declare it as nullable by adding `?` after the type.

```
DateTime? nullable_dt = new DateTime?();
```

Assuming that `nullable_dt` has been set to `null`, the `datagridview` will show an empty cell where the value from `nullable_dt` has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
batchMembersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[16].Value = DateTime.MinValue;

                    if ((DateTime)(batchMembersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[16].Value) == DateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        dataGridViewTextBoxColumn12.DefaultCellStyle.Format = ("");
                    }
```